# The return of my function is a pandas dataframe object, but I recieve a tuple. What is happening and how can i recieve the object as DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a function where I make an pandas DataFrame object, that I place in the return part of the code, when i print type() i get   `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`, but when i print the type() in the receiving code I get `<class 'tuple'>`

Is it supposed to be like this or am I doing anything wrong? 
**Removed Code after i got help and it was answered**
The resolve was that I had included a bool statement in addition to the pandas data frame in the return statement

Comment: Could you share your function ?

Comment: Uploaded parts of the code

Comment: Are you sure that the `assemble_dataframe` function is being called from within the `t1.extractdata` function ?

Comment: You are right, there is a code between, I included it in the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the receiver code, you may have to change the following ( check the `index` in `e` ) -

```
while True:
    c=c+1
    e = tl.extractdata(rawlink,c)
    if e:
        print(type(e[1]),e[1])
```

The reason is that the `extract_data` function is actually returning a tuple ( `True`, `horsetable`).

Comment: Thank you Sajan, that did the trick. I overlooked that completely :-)